# Use of List inside map C++

Tags: c++

Can I use following syntax:

```
 std::map<int,std::list<int>> mAllData;
```

Where Key Value(int) will be ID of data, and said data could have multiple types so storing all them against said key value. I am trying to use it.

Comment: "said data could have mulitple types"... is `list<int>` just one of those types? Or do you mean you want to have a `list` that stores instances of types other than just `int`?

Comment: No data will have multiple instances so all those instances I want to store in a list against its ID(which will be key value) To explain it more take example as one of my data has ID "10" this value wil sit in key of mAllData then this data of ID may have instances of ID say 10000,200000,40000 so I just wanna make list of this instances and keep it with its data ID.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question nor your comment. Are you saying you want an ID to have multiple values? Or you want an ID to have multiple values that each have different types?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
std::map<int,std::list<int>> my_map;
my_map[10].push_back(10000);
my_map[10].push_back(20000);
my_map[10].push_back(40000);
```

Your compiler may not support the two closing angle brackets being right next to each other yet, so you might need `std::map<int,std::list<int> > my_map`.

With C++11 `my_map` can be initialized more efficiently:

```
std::map<int,std::list<int>> my_map {{10, {10000,20000,40000}}};
```

Also, if you just want a way to store multiple values per key, you can use std::multimap.

```
std::multimap<int,int> my_map;
my_map.insert(std::make_pair(10,10000));
my_map.insert(std::make_pair(10,20000));
```

And in C++11 this can be written:

```
std::multimap<int,int> my_map {{10,10000},{10,20000}};
```

Comment: I like your answer better, it's more complete

Comment: I can't believe I did not know about `std::multimap` (well I knew about it, just never used it)! I usually used `std::map<K, std::vector<V>>`. Awesome... now I feel like an inexperienced hobbyist.