# How to retrieve string of keys out of nested map at same time

Tags: c++, stdmap, stdlist

I have a nested `std::map` of student info that looks like this:

```
{
 "class":[
         "student":{
             "name":"Collin",
             "average":"100",
             "family":{
             "%type":"nuclear",
             "%parent":"divorced",
             "#text":"3"
             } //family
          } //student
          "student":{
             "name":"Jamie",
             "average":"95",
             "family":{
             "%type":"nuclear",
             "%parent":"single",
             "#text":"2"
             } //family
          } //student
   ] //class
}//overall Map

where(above) - {} represents a Map
             - [] represents a List
```

I'm trying to retrieve the info like this:

```
std::string student0Name = l_mapClassOfStudents[std::string("class")][std::string("student")][0][std::string("name")]; //see error message about operator for [ before student
```

However, I'm getting no operator [] matches these operands. This is at the [ right before student in the line above.

I saw this [list inside map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192570/use-of-list-inside-map-c), but it doesn't say how to get items out.

EDIT: This is what I wound up with, using our internal definitions of String, VariantMap, VariantList, Variant (hopefully they map closely to standard Variant, VariantMap, VariantList, but I'm not sure if it does or not):

```
//Collin
VariantMap familyInfo0;
familyInfo0[String("%type")] = Variant("nuclear");
familyInfo0[String("%parent")] = Variant("single");
familyInfo0[String("#text")] = Variant("3");
VariantMap studentInfo0;
studentInfo0[String("name")] = Variant("Collin");
studentInfo0[String("average")] = Variant("100");
studentInfo0[String("family")] = familyInfo0;

VariantMap classInfo;
VariantList students;
VariantMap studentMap0;
studentMap0[String("student")] = studentInfo0;
VariantMap studentMap1;
studentMap1[String("student")] = studentInfo1;
students.push_back(studentMap0);
students.push_back(studentMap1);
classInfo[String("class")] = students;
Variant student0Name = classInfo[String("class")].cast<VariantList>()[0].cast<VariantMap>()[String("name")];
```

Comment: Show some code. You say that l_mapClassOfStudents is a map<string,list<....>> but you try to access it as if it was map<string, map<...>>.

Comment: I'm guessing if `class` is an array of students that you don't need the `[std::string('student')]`

Comment: Could you give us the actual type of your container?

Comment: Incidentally, if you weren't aware of this already (and are using a suitable compiler), you may find that the `""s` way of doing string literals makes this sort of code a bit more readable. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Comment: The container type changes at each level, according to the { [ diagram above.

Comment: @Rook we have c++ 98 so I don't think we can do what is at the link you show.

Comment: Fair enough. But it is 2017 now; maybe the people in charge of the compiler choice could do with reminding of this!

Comment: It goes deep into our product, unfortunately.  It would take a ton of work to change it.

Comment: @Michele *The container type changes at each level, according to the { [ diagram above* -- Please post the actual **C++** definition of your container, not a JSON-like description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the students are in a list, use front() to retrieve the first element:

```
std::string student0Name = l_mapClassOfStudents[std::string("class")].front()[std::string("name")];
```

I think a better structure would be something like

```
typedef map<string,string> Student;
typedef list<Student> Class;
typedef list<Class> School;
```

Lists are usually used for iterating through.
Alternatively you could use vector instead of list to access them by number:

```
typedef map<string,string> Student;
typedef vector<Student> Class;
typedef vector<Class> School;
cout << thisSchool[3][2]["name"]; // name of the 3rd student in the 4th class, if thisSchool is of type School (and enough classes and students exist)
```

Comment: I wanted to get the ith element, though.  Shouldn't it work to do [0]? Plus I want to string the list and map info together.  Students are in a list but their sub-contents are in a map.

Comment: Lists do not have a random access operator (use vectors instead). Otherwise you might want to go through using iterator, but I would have to see the type of your expression.

Comment: Also I think the structure does not make a lot of sense, if you have maps with only one key (e.g. student or class).

Comment: The student level could have duplicates (two student tags), so that's why it's a list at that point.  Maybe a vector is what I need...

Comment: Either use vectors or go through the lists via iterators.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to get it out if it was a vector at the [0], inside the class map, with a map inside the vector.

Comment: They don't want an iterator.  They want to access it like I show in my student0Name line of code.

Comment: No, if it'd a map of string, vector for class, which doesn't compile.  Student is a map of string, map.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144858/discussion-between-gerriet-and-michele).

Comment: I'm going to accept this one, although a standard map doesn't quite work to hold map<string,string> as well as map<string,map> like I need in my student data.  A VariantMap and VariantList, in Variant are probably what I need in a higher version of c++.

Comment: Using our internal definitions of String, VariantMap, VariantList, and Variant: Variant student0Name = classInfo[String("class")].cast<VariantList>()[0].cast<VariantMap>()[String("name")];